# “Around here somewhere” or “Somewhere around here”

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine someone has lost something and he/she is anxiously looking for it everywhere. you as a witness of the whole story decide to cool them down. You are going to ask them not be worried just because you saw the lost thing somewhere near the place they are looking for it.
I was wondering which construction below is more correct to be said and why?

> **a)** It’s around here somewhere.  [Once a native one told me this is the correct version of this sentence.] 
> **b)** It’s somewhere around here. [While, this option sounds much more correct to me.]

Please let me know about them.

Comment: Both fine......

Comment: I agree that both are grammatical. Depending on intonation, the final word of a sentence is often emphasized so "around here **somewhere**" could emphasize the uncertainly of location while "somewhere around **here**" could emphasize that it's nearby.